# Last Ubunutu 20.04 update broke something with the keyboard mappings

Tags: updates, 20.04, shortcut-keys

I'm on a laptop and I updated my ubuntu with the live patch. Since then my Bluetooth mouse clicks get swapped after each reconnection of the mouse and I have a problem with some shortcuts my auxiliary keyboard which is connected via USB to the laptop. More specifically the ctrl+shift+tab which is supposed to go reverse on tabs in the browser doesn't work, or ctrl+arrow which is supposed to jump on a word in the text editor does not work. I'm not sure how to debug this problem and pin down the package that caused these issues.

Answer (score 0):

I found a [related post](https://superuser.com/questions/1348136/ctrlaltshift-shortcuts-not-working-on-linux-mint-19) that seems it could have addressed the issue but before getting a chance to do try it a new update came and the aforementioned problems are now resolved. I'm not sure what package was responsible for the problems but here's my apt log before and after the update that fixed it.

The update that caused the problem:

```
Start-Date: 2020-10-08  15:07:37
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.639'
Upgrade: bolt:amd64 (0.8-4, 0.8-4ubuntu1), gir1.2-mutter-6:amd64 (3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2, 3.36.6-1ubuntu0.20.04.2), gcc-9-base:amd64 (9.3.0-10ubuntu2, 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04), vino:amd64 (3.22.0-5ubuntu2, 3.22.0-5ubuntu2.1), gcc-10-base:amd64 (10-20200411-0ubuntu1, 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04), gcc-10-base:i386 (10-20200411-0ubuntu1, 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04), cpp-9:amd64 (9.3.0-10ubuntu2, 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04), libitm1:amd64 (10-20200411-0ubuntu1, 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04), libgfortran-9-dev:amd64 (9.3.0-10ubuntu2, 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04), qdigidoc4:amd64 (4.2.6.83-2004, 4.2.7.85-2004), libasan5:amd64 (9.3.0-10ubuntu2, 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04), libquadmath0:amd64 (10-20200411-0ubuntu1, 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04), libmutter-6-0:amd64 (3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2, 3.36.6-1ubuntu0.20.04.2), libstdc++-9-dev:amd64 (9.3.0-10ubuntu2, 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04), mutter-common:amd64 (3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2, 3.36.6-1ubuntu0.20.04.2), libgcc1:amd64 (1:10-20200411-0ubuntu1, 1:10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04), libtsan0:amd64 (10-20200411-0ubuntu1, 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04), libubsan1:amd64 (10-20200411-0ubuntu1, 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04), g++-9:amd64 (9.3.0-10ubuntu2, 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04), libgfortran5:amd64 (10-20200411-0ubuntu1, 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04), gcc-9:amd64 (9.3.0-10ubuntu2, 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04), gfortran-9:amd64 (9.3.0-10ubuntu2, 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04), liblsan0:amd64 (10-20200411-0ubuntu1, 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04), libgomp1:amd64 (10-20200411-0ubuntu1, 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04), libgomp1:i386 (10-20200411-0ubuntu1, 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04), libgcc-s1:amd64 (10-20200411-0ubuntu1, 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04), libgcc-s1:i386 (10-20200411-0ubuntu1, 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04), libatomic1:amd64 (10-20200411-0ubuntu1, 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04), libatomic1:i386 (10-20200411-0ubuntu1, 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04), libcc1-0:amd64 (10-20200411-0ubuntu1, 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04), libstdc++6:amd64 (10-20200411-0ubuntu1, 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04), libstdc++6:i386 (10-20200411-0ubuntu1, 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04), libgcc-9-dev:amd64 (9.3.0-10ubuntu2, 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04), mutter:amd64 (3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2, 3.36.6-1ubuntu0.20.04.2)
End-Date: 2020-10-08  15:08:00
```

The update that fixed it:

```
Start-Date: 2020-10-14  15:27:48
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.1601'
Install: linux-image-5.4.0-51-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-51.56, automatic), linux-headers-5.4.0-51-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-51.56, automatic), linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-51-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-51.56, automatic), linux-modules-5.4.0-51-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-51.56, automatic), linux-headers-5.4.0-51:amd64 (5.4.0-51.56, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-headers-generic:amd64 (5.4.0.48.51, 5.4.0.51.54), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (5.4.0-48.52, 5.4.0-51.56), xserver-common:amd64 (2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.4, 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu3ppa3), xserver-xorg-core:amd64 (2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.4, 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu3ppa3), linux-image-generic:amd64 (5.4.0.48.51, 5.4.0.51.54), xserver-xorg-legacy:amd64 (2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.4, 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu3ppa3), skypeforlinux:amd64 (8.65.0.76, 8.65.0.78), xserver-xephyr:amd64 (2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.4, 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu3ppa3), xwayland:amd64 (2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.4, 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu3ppa3), file-roller:amd64 (3.36.2-0ubuntu1, 3.36.3-0ubuntu1), linux-generic:amd64 (5.4.0.48.51, 5.4.0.51.54)
End-Date: 2020-10-14  15:29:10
```

For the record I will insert my kernel and gnome-shell info here as well:

```
Linux 5.4.0-51-generic #56-Ubuntu SMP Mon Oct 5 14:28:49 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
GNOME Shell 3.36.4
```